# Input string array one character at a time

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, file-handling

I came across a problem in which I need to load data from a text file, and than save it into an array of `string` type. My approach is to consider the array as a 2D array, but of `char` type.

This is my code:

```
string *rollno;
rollno=new string[2];
string line;

ifstream in("file.txt",ios::app);

int i=0;
char single;
in.get(single);

while (single != '.') {
    for (int j=0; single!=',' || single!='.'; j++) {
        rollno[i][j]=single;\\saving in array character wise
    }

    in.get(single);\\getting the next line 
    i++;
}

cout<<rollno[0]<<endl<<rollno[1];\\checking
```

Could anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What is the contents of the file? What if you increase `i` beyond `1` (which is the top index of `rollno`)? Or what if you use any indexing into an ***empty*** string?

Comment: @RSahu  I need to make a school management system for which I am required to input from a file.

Comment: @joachimPileborg The file has the details of student in following format:

Roll No,First Name,Last Name,age,City.
currently I am taking size 2 just to test. And the file I am using has data for two students only.

Comment: You kind of missed the important part of my comment, that indexing an empty string will index out of bounds. If a string if empty then *any* index will be out of bounds.

Comment: You still haven't asked a question. You explained (a tiny bit) what your objective is but not what you are struggling with.

Comment: I am struggling with storing data( character by character) in an array of string type. Pointing towards line 15  @DietmarKühl

Comment: I still couldn't get what you are trying to say. Are you trying to say that I can not use string arrays unless I initialize them where they are declared? @joachimpileborg

Comment: A `std::string` object *isn't* an array, and it doesn't matter, you can't index out of bounds. If the size of  *real* array is zero, what do you think would be a valid index?

Comment: I read somewhere that strings are character arrays. So you can access them like you access an array. I am not sure about inputting. @joachimpileborg

Comment: You can use a `std::string` object similar to an array, but it doesn't mean you can use an index that is out of bounds, neither for `std::stirng`, `std::vector`, and actual array, or anything else that allows indexing. If you want to ***append*** a character to a `std::string` object, use e.g. the `+=` operator, like `rollno[i] += single;`. After making sure `i` is within bounds. Just think about it logically, if something has the size zero, how could you be able to access element `x`?

Comment: And also, if you want a dynamic array use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. You might also want to read e.g. [this `std::string` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). As well as [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to find a good beginners book.

Comment: Sure - you string has zero size. You'll need extend the string to an appropriate size before you can access a character. You can, for example, use `push_back()` to add each character. You also need to check whether you successfully read a character, BTW.

Comment: So I can not use rollno[i][j] in line no 15? Then what would you suggest? @joachimpileborgh

Comment: That means storing one character at a time is not possible. I'll have to temporarily save the complete roll number to a string variable and then save it to my array later. @dietmarkühl

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but from the looks of it, wouldn't this be what you're looking for?

(Assuming `i` is the array index, and `j` is for `std::string.operator[]`, as appears to be the case.)

```
// ...

while (single != '.') {
    while (single != ',' && single != '.') {
        rollno[i] += single; // appending to string.
    }

    in.get(single); //getting the next line 
    i++;
}
```

You can append a `char` to a `std::string` with `operator+=`, as described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/).

Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but `(single != ',' || single != '.')` will always evaluate to true; if `single == ','`, then `single != '.'`, and vice versa.  If you want it to stop processing once it encounters either delimiter, then you use a logical AND to make sure it stops if either check fails.

(Apologies for any typoes or mistakes I may have missed.)